# Android ListView onOverScrolled и onOverScroll никогда не вызываются на 2.3

Tags: listview, android

Хотел сделать, чтоб при оверскроле LisvView оттягивался. Но не получается. Видел много решений, но они не на всех устройствах работают.

В моём классе:

```
public class BounceListView extends ListView{
...
    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        LOG.d("onOverScrolled");

}

@Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
            int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
            int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
            LOG.d("overScrollBy");
    }

}
```

Никогда не срабатывают эти события. Единственный вариант - полностью все onTouch события переопределять? Или может есть что-то попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, сделал. Кому интересно, залил на [Github](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-sdk-examples/tree/master/OverScrollListView).

Работает на 2.3+

Answer (score 3):

Возможно это вам поможет. Код взят [тут](https://code.google.com/p/techbooster/source/browse/trunk/overscrolledActivity/src/org/jpn/techbooster/sample/overscrolledActivity/OverScrollListView.java?spec=svn345&r=345).

```
public class OverScrollListView extends ListView {
    private final String TAG = "ListView";

    public OverScrollListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
            init();
    }

    public OverScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
    }

    private void init() {
            // 常にオーバースクロールで設定
            setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    }

    // オーバースクロール
    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
                    int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
                    int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {

            // オーバーライド
            return super.overScrollBy(0, deltaY, 0, scrollY, 0, scrollRangeY, 0,
                            200, isTouchEvent);

    }

    // オーバースクロール実行後
    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX,
                    boolean clampedY) {

            Log.v(TAG, "scrollX:" + scrollX + " scrollY:" + scrollY + " clampedX:"
                            + clampedX + " clampedY:" + clampedX);

            super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

    }
}
```

Comment: Не-не, пробовал уже подобные штуки. На большинстве устройств не работает. Но на некоторых не хочет всё равно работать почему-то.

Comment: Для OverScroll минимальное API - 9. Может из-за этого?

Comment: @Deadkenny так тогда бы выдавало, что deprecated. Но не вижу этого в описании метода)

Comment: @Suvitruf http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onOverScrolled(int, int, boolean, boolean) тут справа посмотрите. Написано 
Added in API level 9. И вообще уже пора бы отбрасывать это старье. Берите за минимальный API 14 :)

Comment: @Deadkenny 2.3 ещё до сих пор много

Comment: Чем раньше им откажут в поддержке, тем быстрее они обновят телефон :) У меня например из 70к установок всего 7 процентов на 2.3 сидит. У остальных выше.